# Segmentation Fault: C-Program migrating from HPUX to Linux

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to migrate a small c program from hpux to linux. The project compiles fine but crashes at runtime showing me a segmentation fault. I've already tried to see behind the mirror using strace and gdb but still don't understand. The relevant (truncated) parts:

**tts_send_2.c**

Contains a method

```
int sequenznummernabgleich(int sockfd, char *snd_id, char *rec_id, int timeout_quit) {
  TS_TEL_TAB tel_tab_S01;
  int n;

  # truncated
}
```

which is called from within that file like this:

```
. . .
. . .  
switch(sequenznummernabgleich(sockfd,c_snd_id,c_rec_id,c_timeout_quit)) {

         /* kritischer Fehler */
         case -1:
. . .
. . .
```

when calling that method I'm presented a segmentation fault (gdb output):

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000403226 in sequenznummernabgleich (sockfd=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff62f94c>, 
    snd_id=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff62f940>, rec_id=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff62f938>, 
    timeout_quit=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff62f934>) at tts_snd_2.c:498
498 int sequenznummernabgleich(int sockfd, char *snd_id, char *rec_id, int timeout_quit) {
```

which I just don't understand. When I'm stepping to the line where the method is called using gdb, all the variables are looking fine:

```
1008    switch(sequenznummernabgleich(sockfd,c_snd_id,c_rec_id,c_timeout_quit)) {
    (gdb) p sockfd
    $9 = 8
    (gdb) p &sockfd
    $10 = (int *) 0x611024 <sockfd>
    (gdb) p c_snd_id
    $11 = "KR", '\000' <repeats 253 times>
    (gdb) p &c_snd_id
    $12 = (char (*)[256]) 0xfde220 <c_snd_id>
    (gdb) p c_rec_id
    $13 = "CO", '\000' <repeats 253 times>
    (gdb) p &c_rec_id
    $14 = (char (*)[256]) 0xfde560 <c_rec_id>
    (gdb) p c_timeout_quit
    $15 = 20
    (gdb) p &c_timeout_quit
    $16 = (int *) 0xfde660 <c_timeout_quit>
```

I've also created an strace output. Here's the last part concerning the code shown above:

[strace output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0uDd.png)

Any ideas ? I've searched the web and of course stackoverflow for hours without finding a really similar case.

Thanks

Kriz

Comment: What line is it crashing on? Can you post the code before the call to your function (i.e., the variable declarations and code that sets them to their values at the time of the call)?

Comment: I think you need to step into the function, and see what the variables look like then.

Comment: C does not support _methods_. Only functions.

Comment: Is there a VLA declared just before you call that function?

Comment: @Andy Schweig: That's quite a lot of initialization code but as I showed the sysout of gdb, they are all filled with useful data before jumping into the function.

Comment: @user3386109 I did this multiple times and the result is an immediate segfault as shown above. The code of the function itself doesn't get execute anymore.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry for the wrong wording. I'm mainly a Java Developer :-)

Comment: @rici all arrays in the program are defined with fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used an HP/UX in eons but do hazily remember enough for the following suggestions:

Make sure you're initializing variables / struts correctly. Use calloc instead of malloc.

Also don't assume a specific bit pattern order: eg low byte then high byte. Ska endian-ness of the machine. There are usually macros in the compiler that will handle the appropriate ordering for you.

Answer (score -2):

**Update 15.10.16**

After debugging for even more hours I found the real Problem. On the first line of the Method "sequenznummernabgleich" is a declaration of a struct

```
TS_TEL_TAB tel_tab_S01;
```

This is defined as following:

```
typedef struct {
   TS_BOF_REC   bof;
   TS_REM_REC   rem;
   TS_EOF_REC   eof;
   int          bof_len;
   int          rem_len;
   int          eof_len; 
   int          cnt;     
   char         teltyp[LEN_TELTYP+1];
   TS_TEL_ENTRY entries[MAX_TEL];
} TS_TEL_TAB;
```

and it's embedded struct TS_TEL_ENTRY

```
typedef struct {
   int  len;
   char tel[MAX_TEL_LEN];
} TS_TEL_ENTRY;
```

The problem is that the value for `MAX_TEL_LEN` had been changed from 512 to 1024 and thus the struct almost doubled in size what lead to that the **STACK SIZE was not big enough anymore**.

**SOLUTION**
Simply set the stack size from 8Mb to 64Mb. This can be achieved using `ulimit` command (under linux).

> List current stack size: `ulimit -s`
>
> Set stack size to 64Mb: `ulimit -s 65535`

**Note**: Values for stack size are in kB.

For a good short ref on `ulimit` command have a look @ [ss64](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)

Comment: XY solution. While it solves the problem in the first place, it is the wrong approach. Much like you have a flat tire and put a skateboard in its place instead of fixing the tire.

Comment: @Olaf the memory requirement got bigger so I gave it more. What's wrong with that solution ?

Comment: I commented what the problem is. If tools like Firefox, etc. work with the standard stack, I doubt your program will be an exception. Do some research, get rid of blinkers,

Comment: The proper solution is to use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc`, `calloc`, etc.) instead of arrays.  A 64MB stack is a laughable "solution".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the advice. I'll delegate a ticket to assign the objects on the heap instead of stack and afterward reduce the stack size back to 8Mb. I learned programming C/C++ while studying but never used it anymore the last ten years ;-)